# Run JS onLoad of React-DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using RESTool (https://github.com/dsternlicht/RESTool) as an API-UI and I need to run a js-script after React has rendered everything. window.onload and $(document).ready do not work.

Comment: add your code here, along with error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using react function components.
For every side effect happening after rendering use the useEffect-hook (have a read in the docs if you dont know it, you will need it very often). Then you can dynamically import your script and use it in the hook. In the I have included a network request to load the script in case you dont serve it by your own.

```
function Component() {

  useEffect(() => {

    // This happens after rendering with a script requested from an API
    makeAPIRequest.then((script) => script.doThisAndThat())

    // This assumes you have your script locally, then you can import it   dynamically to speed up initial render. Note that when dynamically importing you must default export the script
    import('./myScriptThatShouldExecuteAfterRender').then((script) => script.doThis())

  })

  render(
    <SomeThing />
  )
}
```

You can also just import your script normally and then execute it in the useEffect. The dynamic import is just to load the script after you have rendered something to the user and to improve UX.